# Getting self signed certificate in certificate chain in node.js from Google Maps API call

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, tls1.2, self-signed

When making a request I receive a

```
{Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' }
```

I have tried the following from other SO threads and the NPM recommended solutions:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
npm install npm -g --ca=null
npm config set ca=""
```

Code with the call is here:

```
const request = require('request');
const yargs = require('yargs');

request({
 url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
 address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia`,
 json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
 console.log(error);
 //console.log(`Address: ${body.results[0].formatted_address}`);
 });
```

When the commented console log is run, body is undefined.

I also just uninstalled node/npm and freshly installed it with the same results.

How to fix?